# Jquery handle on click event for multiple variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I set up my html with 4 heroes pictures on the top that the user can click to use as their own hero or their opponent. It's like a street fighter kind of deal. So the user have to select the first hero to be their own player (and it's their own player for the rest of the game). The other 3 heroes are going to be the user's opponents. And the user can select which opponent to fight first. So I set up my script that all 4 heroes have the same class ".heroes-pic". How to disable the on click event after the first hero was selected (to be the user's player)? And then enable it so the user can continue to choose their opponent? Here's my script

```
//player choose their hero
$(".heroes-pic").on("click", function() {

  player = heroes[$(this).attr("id")];
  //showing player
  $("#player img").attr('src', player.iconUrl);
  $("#player-damage").text('Damage: ' + player.damage);
  $("#player-hp").text('HP: ' + player.hp);
  $("#player").show();
  $(this).hide();
  $("#display-message").find("h2").text('Please Choose Your Opponent');
  $(".heroes-pic").off("click");
})

//player choose their opponent
$(".heroes-pic").on("click");
$(".heroes-pic").on("click", function () {

  enemy = heroes[$(this).attr("id")];
  //showing enemy
  $("#enemy img").attr('src', enemy.iconUrl);
  $("#enemy-counter-damage").text('Counter Damage: ' + enemy.counterDamage);
  $("#enemy-hp").text('HP: ' + enemy.hp);
  $("#enemy").show();
  $(this).hide();

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set up a variable **outside** of the click handler to handle whether the hero has been selected or not, defaulting it to `false`. Then inside of the click handler set this flag to `true` after the first click. This way, the logic for the `else` conditional will trigger on subsequent clicks.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
let hero_chosen = false;
let opponent_chosen = false;

$(".heroes-pic").on("click", function() {
  // player choose their hero
  if (hero_chosen === false) {
    console.log('player choice');
    hero_chosen = true;
  }
  // player choose their opponent
  else if (opponent_chosen === false) {
    console.log('opponent choice');
    opponent_chosen = true;
  }
  // both choices are made
  else {
    console.log('both choices have already been made');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="heroes-pic">One</div>
<div class="heroes-pic">Two</div>
<div class="heroes-pic">Three</div>
<div class="heroes-pic">Four</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach the enemy handler only after the first handler has been triggered:

```
//player choose their hero
$(".heroes-pic").on("click", function() {

  player = heroes[$(this).attr("id")];
  //showing player
  $("#player img").attr('src', player.iconUrl);
  $("#player-damage").text('Damage: ' + player.damage);
  $("#player-hp").text('HP: ' + player.hp);
  $("#player").show();
  $(this).hide();
  $("#display-message").find("h2").text('Please Choose Your Opponent');
  $(".heroes-pic").off("click");

  //player choose their opponent
  $(".heroes-pic").on("click", pickEnemy);
});

function pickEnemy() {
  enemy = heroes[$(this).attr("id")];
  //showing enemy
  $("#enemy img").attr('src', enemy.iconUrl);
  $("#enemy-counter-damage").text('Counter Damage: ' + enemy.counterDamage);
  $("#enemy-hp").text('HP: ' + enemy.hp);
  $("#enemy").show();
  $(this).hide();
}
```